# Convert SQL Query to Django ORM

Tags: django, orm, subquery

I am new to Django ORM and am struggling to convert the following query into ORM.  Appreciate any help/guidance.  The dates/times are not in a particular order.

Thanks in advance

**SQL Query:** 
'''
SELECT 
A.Person_id, 
A.Dept_id,
A.score_date,
A.score 
FROM 
borrowerdeptscore AS A 
INNER JOIN  
(
SELECT Person_id, Dept_id, MAX(score_date) AS Max_date FROM borrowerdeptscore GROUP BY Person_id, Dept_id
) AS B 
ON 
A.Person_id = B.Person_id 
AND  
A.Dept_id = B.Dept_id 
AND 
A.score_date = B.Max_date 
'''

**The Django Class**:
'''
class BorrowerDeptScore (models.Model):
Person= models.ForeignKey('Person')
Dept= models.ForeignKey('Dept')

```
score_date = models.DateTimeField()<br/>
score = models.DecimalField()<br/>
```

'''

The closest I got to an answer was the following, however I cannot add the "score" to the queryset.  Not sure what I am missing or forgot here.

latestscores = BorrowerDeptScore .objects.values('Person_id', 'Dept_id').annotate(max_date=Max('score_date'))

Comment: To quickly check you're getting there, you can do `latestscores.query`. Not sure if I can figure it out atm from my brain.

Comment: the .query returns 
SELECT Person_id, 
Dept_id, 
MAX(score_date) AS "max_date" 
FROM borrowerdeptscore 
GROUP BY Person_id, Dept_id <br>

I am able to get it to run using raw sql.  Am wondering if there is an easier ORM way to do this sort of query.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly, by try this:

```
   latestscores = BorrowerDeptScore .objects.values(
    'Person', 'Dept','score ').annotate(
     max_date=Max('score_date'))
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.  This creates a group on the score value which then results in multiple records, vs only one record for the maximum date.